# Looking for an 80's-90's cartoon with a shapeshifter

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, shape-shifter

This might be a little difficult to locate, because I only remember one specific scene. It's a pretty memorable scene, though, so maybe someone can help me.

Basically, there's this small shapeshifting... thing. (Alien? Nanite colony? Something like that.) It's trying to break into a secure military base, and needs to defeat a voice-activated lock. It's already killed (I think) and examined somebody with access to the room, but it isn't big enough to shapeshift into a full human. So, it only replicates the guy's lungs, throat, and head in order to generate the right voice to fool the lock.

It would be a pretty old show, maybe 1980's to the 1990's. I'm about 90% sure it was animated, and I'm pretty sure it wasn't an anime, if that helps.

Comment: I recall something similar happens to Dr. Manhattan in the Watchmen comic. He has to learn to reconstitute himself bit by bit, and spends a while as just a floating nervous system.